# PhoneStateListener not giving the number dialed / called

Tags: android, service, permissions, state, phone-state-listener

According to documentation, the PhoneStateListener is a class that handles the phone state change,
the onCallStateChanged method should get 2 parameters , state (integer) and String -> phone number.

```
package com.eddieharari.shippit;

import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhoneStateBcListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String phone) {

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("SHIPIT","Call State Idle");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("SHIPIT","Call State OffHook:");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d("SHIPIT","Call State Ringing:"+phone);
                break;
        }
        if (phone == null) {
            Log.d("SHIPPIT","Number is null");
        } else Log.d("SHIPPIT","Number is not Null");
    }
}
```

The above code is my PhoneStateListener class, and I call it from a service:

```
package com.eddieharari.shippit;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class GetCallService extends Service {
    TelephonyManager telephony;
    PhoneStateBcListener myListener = new PhoneStateBcListener();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("SHIPT","Inside Oncreate");
        Log.d("SHIPPIT","Started Receiver");
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(myListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent i, int start ) {
        Log.d("SHIPIT","Inside START");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("SHIPIT","Inside Ondestroy");

    }
}
```

I start the service from my main activity however I never get the number (it's not NULL but it is an empty string). I have seen examples of people using Broadcast receiver but I don't understand why the documentation states that the number should be available using PhoneStateListener.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"> </uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".GetCallService"
        android:enabled="true" />
</application>
```

Comment: I have some progress as it seems that with NEW API level i need to ask permissions on run time, however even than i can only get incomming numbers and not outgoing numbers as well as it does not work on an emulator , only on actual device...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me to get the dialed number / incoming number:

1. Here is my main activity:

   package com.eddieharari.shippit;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.Manifest;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.IntentFilter;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
   import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
    TelephonyManager tm;
    PhoneStateListener mReceiver = new mPhoneStateListener();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("SHIPIT","NOT HAVE PERMISSION FOR PHONE_STATE");
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},0);} else Log.d("SHIPIT","HAVE THE PHONE STATE PERMISSIONS");
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("SHIPIT","NOT HAVE PERMISSION FOR CALL_LOG");
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},0);} else Log.d("SHIPIT","HAVE THE READ CALL LOG");

        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(mReceiver,mPhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


        Log.d("SHIPIT","Registered the receiver");

    }

    @Override
    protected  void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }
   ```

   }

Note that you need to ask permissions on the manifest and also on run time as you can see here... There is no need for a broadcast listener , only phonestate listener ... here is my phone state listener class:

```
package com.eddieharari.shippit;

import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class mPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String number){
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("SHIPIT","State is IDLE");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("SHIPIT","State is OffHook:"+number);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d("SHIPIT","State is Ringing:"+number);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```